# Get X coordinate method for context.fillRect() method - Javascript, Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-engine

For the variable snake1, is there a set method so that I can later get the x and y coordinates.

Something like snake1.getX() or something? Can't seem to find anything

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var snake1 = context.fillRect(x,y, snakeHeight, snakeWidth);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such methods, see the reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp

You can fill the variable snake1 yourself by doing this for example: `var snake1 = {'x': x, 'y': y};` then access it like any other object: `snake1.x`

Answer (score 1):

[According to MDN, fillRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#fillRect%28%29) doesn't return any value at all, so snake1 won't actually be set to anything.

However, x and y are values you have already calculated to pass in, so you can save them wherever you want.

Comment: Ok I'm confused. I assigned it to snake1 so I can later have control of the rectangle variable e.g. change its fill colour, How would I go about that?

Comment: @FootsieNG The rectangle is not an object that can be moved or edited, you are just telling the browser to draw a particular shape on the canvas, just like painting with a brush.